# Different form and color of checkbox on android activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-sdk-2.3

I have an Android app with this portion of main activity:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vistaAnni"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:text="1998" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/CheckBox02"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".1" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/CheckBox07"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".1" />
```

On the main activity class, I need another linear layout with other checks box.

```
LinearLayout myView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vistaAnni);
        Log.v("blah", "Crea tabella dinamica");
        for(int i = 0; i < anni.size();i++){
            Log.v("blah", "Creo colonna: "+anni.get(i));

            LinearLayout newLine = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            newLine.setOrientation(1);
            newLine.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


            TextView testo = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            testo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, .1f));
            testo.setText(anni.get(i));
            newLine.addView(testo);

            CheckBox check1c = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            check1c.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, .1f));
            newLine.addView(check1c);

            CheckBox check2c = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            check2c.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, .1f));
            newLine.addView(check2c);
myView.addView(newLine);
```

The system creates the box and the text fine, but with different colors and hardly visibility.

But I haven't customized it over activity.xml it or over activity.java. Why this change?
This is a sreen of app:

[image]

Comment: Use the activity context and not the application context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change all:

CheckBox check1c = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());

with:

CheckBox check1c = new CheckBox(this);

as suggested by Luksprog  and works.

Comment: Accept your own answer if everything is ok ;-) .

Comment: I can't now, need waiting 2 days :D